# how to add custom property and method to google map with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps

I wanna add properties like `id` and `label` to `MVCObject` interface so that I can access that properties in `Marker` or `Overlay`, and method like `isOpened` to `InfoWindow` interface so that every `infoWindow` instance created by `InfoWindow` interface have that method.

in JavaScript, I can do this like

```js
marker.id = id
marker.label = label
google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.isOpened = () => {}
```

but the problem I don't know how to modify TypeScript about this.

I have two solutions that don't look ideal.

1. It seems that I can add properties to `google.maps.MVCObject` interface without modifying TypeScript using `get`, `set` method in `MVCObject`, but it's not ideal because this way ignores TypeScript.
2. Modifying `node_modules/@types/google.maps` is also another solution I have, but I don't know whether it's nice idea to directly change `node_modules`.

please let me know nicer ways to handle this TypeScript problem. thanks~!

I'm using `react`, `@googlemaps/js-api-loader`, and `@types/google.maps`

Comment: i tried to apply module augmentation or declaration merging, but it was hard for me. so i just made a custom interface with id, label, and isOpened that extends google.maps.InfoWindow. i just need to write //@ts-ignore when adding custom method to google.maps.InfoWindow.prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It not a good idea that to add properties to third-party library since you have to assign all object by your self, you could use `Map` or `WeakMap` to record the relationship of that object and properties defined by yourself.

And there is a way to extends the definition of package by [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), create a `d.ts` file like the following:

```
declare module "<package_name_to_modify>" {
  interface TheInterface {
    // add what you want here
  }
}

export {}
```

Note that it won't works for `type` since it can not be merged.

---

If you insist to modify the definition (or it is a `type`) and you are using `yarn` as package manager, you could try [yarn patch](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/patch) command, it will create a temporary package that can modify as you want. And remember to follow the instruction to save those changes